# How to correctly divide square matrix?

Tags: c++

[image: Matrix like this with 0 in it]

```
const int n = 4, m = 4;
int i, j, k, sum;
srand(time(NULL));

int mat[n][m];
printf("Matrix( %d, %d): \n",n,m);

for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        mat[i][j] = rand()%100-50;
        printf("%4d", mat[i][j]);
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

for(i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < m/2; j++)
    {
        mat[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

How to divide square matrix on 4 equal square blocks? My code divide only 1st part. I think I need to use n/2 < n, but how to do it in cycle?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Could you dispaly an example of a resulting matrix that you would like to get?

Comment: @Damien I added an example of a resulting matrix

Comment: Why not `mat[i][j] = mat[i+n/2][j] = mat[i][j+n/2] = mat[i+n/2][j+n/2]=rand()%100-50`, for `i` and  `j` less than `n/2` ?

Comment: Is the `n` guaranteed to be even?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### First block:

```c
for (int i=0; i<n/2; i++) {
  for(int j=0; j<m/2; j++) {
     // your code
    }
}
```

#### Second block:

```c
for (int i=0; i<n/2; i++) {
  for(int j=m/2; j<m; j++) {
     // your code
    }
}
```

#### Third block:

```c
for (int i=n/2; i<n; i++) {
  for(int j=0; j<m/2; j++) {
     // your code
    }
}
```

#### Forth block:

```c
for (int i=n/2; i<n; i++) {
  for(int j=m/2; j<m; j++) {
     // your code
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you insure that blocks are identical? Note that I am not sure to have understood the question correctly! Not so clear

Comment: @Damien, You're right. The question is not clear enough, but as far I understood from his sample, he was able to traverse the first block of the matrix and trying to traverse the others. 
NB: blocks may not be identical in size.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more compact code that can fetch your matrix blocks by rows sequentially:

```
for (int p = 0; p <= 1, p++)
{
    for (int q = 0; q <= 1, q++)
    {
        for(i = p*n/2; i < (p+1)*n/2; i++)
        {
            for (j = q*m/2; j < (q+1)*m/2; j++)
            {
                mat[i][j] = 0;
             }
         }
    }
}
```